# Using data of Doctrine Collection from OneToMany association in JSON

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've seen many examples of how to set up a OneToMany association between Entities. However, I have not seen anything on how to output the data from an association. (such as converting to JSON or just having a clean array)

So, here is some sample code:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Banks\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="bank")
 **/
class Banks implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * A Bank could have Many Branches
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Branches\Entity\Branches", mappedBy="bank")
     *
     */
    protected $branches;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     *
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'branches' => $this->getBranches()
        ];
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->branches = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getBranches(): Collection
    {
        return $this->branches;
    }

    // ... Other getter/setters removed
}
```

Then we also have the Branches Entity:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Branches\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="branches")
 **/
class Branches implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * A Branch has one Bank
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Banks\Entity\Banks", inversedBy="branches")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bank_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $bank;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $bank_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     *
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'bank_id' => $this->bank_id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'bank' => $this->getBank()
        ];
    }

    public function getBank()
    {
        return $this->bank;
    }

    // ... Other getter/setters removed
}
```

Querying both Entities work fine overall, with calls to `$result->jsonSerialize()`, then returning with `return new JsonResponse($result)` to get a JSON object. Though querying a Branch has the expected result, where I receive the Branch along with the associated Bank as part of the output, the query to Bank is not returning the associated Branches and instead only displays as `"branches": {}`

I know this is because `$branches` is a Collection, but how to output it in a way to be part of the resulting JSON object?

I've tried `$this->branches->toArray()`, but that results in an array of Objects that cannot be encoded to JSON, therefore, ending in an error.

NOTE: The contents (Object) of `$this->getBranches()` does contain the Branches as expected, which can be seen by `$this->branches->count()`. But how to reach them in such a way to allow JsonSerializable to create the JSON?

As requested, here is middleware code leaving up to Entity usage:

A factory is used to create what is needed by the Handler:

```
class BanksViewHandlerFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container) : BanksViewHandler
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get(EntityManager::class);

        $entityManager->getConfiguration()->addEntityNamespace('Banks', 'Banks\Entity');

        $entityRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('Banks:Banks');

        return new BanksViewHandler($entityManager, $entityRepository);
    }
}
```

The Factory calls the Handler:

```
class BanksViewHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    protected $entityManager;
    protected $entityRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager,
        EntityRepository $entityRepository,
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->entityRepository = $entityRepository;
    }

    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        $return = $this->entityRepository->find($request->getAttribute('id'));

$result['Result']['Banks'] = $return->jsonSerialize();

        return new JsonResponse($result);
    }
}
```

The handler returns the JSON.

Comment: Where did you try `$this->branches->toArray()` - in `Banks::jsonSerialize()`?

Comment: Also - are you calling `$result->jsonSerialize()` directly? The intention of the `\JsonSerializable` interface is that `jsonSerialize()` will be called when you pass an object to `json_encode()`; i.e: `$json = json_encode(%$result);`.

Comment: Yes, I tried `$this->branches->toArray()` as the return of `getBranches()` and also within `Banks::jsonSerialize()` as `$this->getBranches()->toArray().

Comment: Okay, that should be correct. Are you then passing your result to `json_encode()` to convert your objects to JSON?

Comment: So, you are saying that proper usage is to still use json_encode($result)? I wasn't aware, and it was working as expected and returning JSON. This is my first time using `JsonSerializable`.

Comment: Exactly. I'll post an answer to elaborate properly.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'll update my examples. I am actually doing `return new JsonResponse($result)` after calling `$result->jsonSerialize()` directly.

Comment: However, this small oversight doesn't answer the question of how to gget the Associated Branches to show in the Bank results.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the controller code as well so we can be sure about what is happening. Ultimately, `JsonResponse` does use `json_encode()` under the hood. Either way, `jsonSerialize` is not to be called explicitly.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and will adjust the code. Thank you for your help. However, the original question still persists.

Comment: I think there is more to this question than can be derived from the code shown - I've done this with nested objects many times and haven't encountered the issues you're describing. SO is suggesting a chat so happy to do that if you want to explore this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183458/discussion-between-adam-culp-and-darragh-enright).

Comment: HI Adam - I updated the chat, and you have identified the issue as far as I am concerned - it's a circular reference between both entities that raises a `CircularReferenceException`. I've elaborated on this in the chat with some suggestions (it depends on your requirements).

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that, when implementing the [`\JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface, calling `jsonSerialize()` directly does not return JSON, and you do not call this method explicitly.

As stated in the docs:

> Objects implementing JsonSerializable can customize their JSON representation when encoded with json_encode().

The intent of implementing this interface is to enforce the `jsonSerialize()` method, which is called internally when passing the object(s) to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php); e.g:

```
$result = $banksRepository->find($id);
$json = json_encode($result);
```

Additionally, if you want to serialize the child Branch entities as well you need to:

1. Implement `\JsonSerializable` for this entity (which you have done)
2. Doctrine will return these Branches as an `ArrayCollection` object, containing all child Branch objects. In order to ensure that `json_encode()` encodes these to JSON properly you need to convert the `ArrayCollection` to an array using `toArray()`.

To illustrate - (as you pointed out you also implemented this):

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'branches' => $this->getBranches()->toArray(), // <-- 
    ];
}
```

This should serialise your Bank and associated Branch entities as expected. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Doing this returns an error. `InvalidArgumentException: Unable to encode data to JSON`

Comment: Can you update you question to include some of your controller code as well?

Comment: Added the HandlerFactory and Handler. No MVC. ;-)